# Reduced Graphene Oxide (RGO) Conductivity vs Everything Else

Tags: electrochemistry, redox, materials, conductivity

Reduced Graphene Oxide (RGO), is the reduced version of Graphene Oxide (GO). Both RGO & GO are easily manufactured when compared to the complex process used to manufacture the 'atom-thick' Graphene. And because RGO & GO are arranged in the same fashion as graphene, they keep similar properties; but nothing in comparison. Nevertheless, it is worth taking a look into the characterization of these properties because we can manufacture them quite easily.

But here's my problem, is it a waste of time to create thin sheets of RGO if there is a material that is more conductive?

So I arrive at my question, is a small sheet RGO's conductivity greater than that of, say, a small sheet of Copper? I have tried researching this every where but have not came up with a solid answer.